# Calculate time taken to execute a C Program Code?

Tags: c, sorting, time

I need to calculate the time that is taken for various Sorting Algorithms in C
I am checking the time taken to sort 100,200,300,400 and 500 elements.

Surprisingly, the time taken to sort them seems to be the same!

Whats wrong in the code that I am getting the same time 0.00000 which is also absurd that it takes 0 seconds to sort the numbers.

Whats wrong in the code that I am getting such results?

What changes must be made to the Code that I get accurate time taken ( in Seconds) for sorting the numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

// Bubble Sort on 100 to 500 elements
int main()
{
    int g;
    //clock_t ti;
    for(g=0;g<5;g++)
    {
    int n, i, j, swap;
    clock_t ti;
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));

    //scanf("%d", &n);
    n=100;
    int array[n*(g+1)]; 



    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        array[i] = rand() % 10000;// Generating random numbers as array entries


    //printf("%f \n",ti);
    ti = clock();
    for (i = 0 ; i < ( n - 1 ); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < n - i - 1; j++)
        {
            if (array[j] > array[j+1]) 
            {
                swap       = array[j];
                array[j]   = array[j+1];
                array[j+1] = swap;
            }
        }
    }

    ti = clock() - ti;
    double time_taken = ((double)ti)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;


    /*for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
        printf("%d \n ", array[i]);*/



    printf("Time Taken to sort %d elements is %f\n",(g+1)*100,time_taken);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The Output That I am getting is:

Time Taken to sort 100 elements is 0.000000

Time Taken to sort 200 elements is 0.000000

Time Taken to sort 300 elements is 0.000000

Time Taken to sort 400 elements is 0.000000

Time Taken to sort 500 elements is 0.000000

Comment: Don't call `srand` more than once, unless you want multiple sequences to be the same.

Comment: try increasing the number of decimal points.

Comment: The behavior of `clock` is much different on different operating systems. Where the C standard stipulates that it measures CPU time (which is perhaps not what you want here) on MS architectures it measures wall clock time. Avoid it if you can.

Comment: Even with your inefficient Bubble Sort, the time to sort a couple of hundreds of items is extremely short on a modern computer. Run your sorting routine on your original data 1,000, 10,000, or 100,000 times in a loop and divide the total time by the number of repetitions.

Comment: I infact used srand since I wanted my multiple sequences different. Using only rand gave me same multiple sequences. What changes do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

`clock()` might have too low of a resolution. Check your value for `CLOCKS_PER_SEC`.

[`clock_gettime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/clock_settime.html) provides a high resolution timer.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer checking CPU cycles directly from CPU register instead of clock(). It's accurate and doesn't have overhead. How it's done depends on used CPU. See e.g. http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/300007

You must of course convert cycles to time if you actually need time. Like this (you must implement CPU specific get_cpu_cycles() according to your system/environment):

```
unsigned long begin = 0, end = 0, time = 0;
begin = get_cpu_cycles();
// Do what you like to measure
end = get_cpu_cycles();

unsigned long diff = end - begin;
const unsigned long cpu_speed = 1000000; // Core speed in kilo Hertz -> cpu_time in milliseconds.
double cpu_time =  ((double) diff) / cpu_speed;

printf("Time: %.6f", cpu_time);
```

Please note that this is hard coded to have CPU speed as 1 GHz.

Comment: How does one convert cycles to time? Like, what change must be made to the code?

Comment: Did you implement get_cpu_cycles()?